# iBeacon の検知を早くする方法

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

## iBeacon の検知を早くする方法が知りたいです

---

ビーコンを30個くらいかき集めて各ビーコンの major と minor を取得して検知した個数をカウントするアプリを作っていますが、遅い時だと全部検知するまでに1分くらいかかることがあります。

ビーコンはパケットを1秒間隔で送出しており、アプリ側でそのパケットを受信するという仕様です。

ここからは予想になりますが、例えばビーコンが1秒間隔で送出して、アプリが1秒単位で受信している場合(startRangingBeaconsInRegion がどれくらいの間隔で受信しているかはわかりませんが...)、ビーコンが1秒間隔で送出しているパケットをアプリ側が取りこぼしているのでしょうか？

できれば数秒で全部検知させたいと思っていますが、検知を早くする方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら教えていただけると助かります。

現状ではビーコンは検知できるものの、30コ程度の検知完了に1分以上かかることがあります。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/107912

Comment: マルチポストのご指摘ですが、テラテイルとここでは読む方が違うのと、色々な意見が欲しかったため、両方に投稿しております。 解決した情報は、どちらにも反映するようにします。 よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答しようとする方への情報提供ですので、質問者さんはお気になさらず。